# How to mask everything but a polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, masking, qgsmapcanvas, mapcanvas

I am able to draw polygons over areas of interest in QGIS. For example via: `Layer` -> `Create Layer` -> `New Temporary Scratch Layer`, name the layer, select `Polygon` as `Geometry type`, `OK`, select the layer in the `Layers` panel, click `Add Polygon Feature` button in the top, draw, finish with `ctrl-click`.

[image]

I am also able to produce a way bigger polygon than this above, remove the one drawn above as a hole in it, and display that one. The end result would be what I want: color/mask everything on the canvas, except the polygon.

**Can I tell QGIS to color/mask out everything except a polygon without the work-around of creating a large polygon with a hole?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a plugin that does what you need: [Mask](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mask/)

Or since 3.22 (no sure the version), there is also a new type of symbology called « [inverted polygon render](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=symbology#inverted-polygon-renderer) », with which you can do a mask outside your polygon

(Get there via: right click on layer name -> `Properties...` -> `Symbology` -> select `Inverted Polygons` from dropdown menu on top.)