How can I create a print layout that is exactly filled with the contents of a shapefile?
I need to create a physical map with exact dimensions. The contents of that map should exactly match the contents of a shapefile layer that has a single rectangle in it:

So the map should just be the red area, everything inside and nothing outside.
How can I create a layout that achieves this? I've tried manual zooming but I need the scale to be exact.

You could mask everything outside the polygon as per this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/442055/how-to-mask-everything-but-a-polygon-in-qgis Then set up a page layout that best matches the polyon.

Look at the buttons capabilities for your map layout's item properties.  If your polygon fully shows in the view map at the scale you want, do that in the main canvas then in your layout item properties set the map extent to match your main canvas extent (see second button from left).  You may have to adjust your page size to show it all at the scale you want and adjust the margins it will give you, and/or use a mask.  If your poly doesn't fit change the scale to show it at a simple multiple of your desired scale, use the button and then in the item properties set the scale to what you want.

you can use the data defined override possibilities of QGIS and override the map extent and the aspect ratio of your mapview in the layout with the following expressions:

override the mapextent of the layout map by the layers extent, here for x_min:
x_min(layer_property('mylayer','extent'))




override the map width, for example for a given map height of 150 mm:
150 * (bounds_width( layer_property('mylayer','extent'))/ bounds_height( layer_property('mylayer','extent')))



